# How to access super class' super class in a Sonar Custom rule?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I'm writing a custom rule that will check whether the class under analysis is extending a type.

For example:

```java
class Bus {
}

class Transport {
}

class PublicTransport extends Transport {
}

class Bus should extend class Transport or a sub class of Transport.

    public class EnsureSuperClassRule extends IssuableSubscriptionVisitor {

        final String SUPER_CLASS = "common.service.SuperService";

        @Override
        public List<Tree.Kind> nodesToVisit() {
        return ImmutableList.of(Tree.Kind.CLASS);
        }

        @Override
        public void visitNode(Tree tree) {

            ClassTree classTree = (ClassTree) tree;
            String className = classTree.simpleName().name();

            if (className.endsWith("Service")) {

                if(classTree.superClass() == null) {
                    return false;
                }

                if (!SUPER_CLASS.equals(localClassTree.superClass().symbolType().fullyQualifiedName())) {
                reportIssue(tree, String.format("The class should extend SuperService or a class of type SuperService"));
                }
            }
          }
        }

    }
```

How can I get the information related to superclass of the superclass?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call

```
Class superClassOfSuperClass = this.class().getSuperClass();
superClassOfSuperClass.method().invoke(this);
```

I'm not sure with your above example as there is a few typo's or misunderstanding with inheritance

Comment: You're talking about standard Java reflection but the post is about SonarQube. `this.class().getSuperClass()` would return the super class of the SonarQube rule/check but not of the type that currently is checked by the rule/check.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect all super classes until `java.lang.Object` was reached like so:

```
@Override
public void visitNode(Tree pTree) {
    final ClassTree classTree = (ClassTree) pTree;

    final Set<String> superclasses = new HashSet<>();
    Type currentSuperclass = classTree.symbol().superClass();
    while (currentSuperclass != null) {
        superclasses.add(currentSuperclass.fullyQualifiedName());
        currentSuperclass = currentSuperclass.symbol().superClass();
    }
    
    // ... do something with superClasses

    super.visitNode(pTree);
}

@Override
public List<Kind> nodesToVisit() {
    return ImmutableList.of(Tree.Kind.CLASS);
}
```

*(Tested with sonar-java-plugin 6.3.0 and sonar-plugin-api 8.2.0)*